# fetch Get google calendar events

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to get my co workers calendar events? for example I have this function where I only get my blue ones booked meeting and such stuff but I'm wondering how can I get from a co workers calendar? I'm able to add my co worker's calendar to mine but it doesn't fetch it because its another color or whatever.. you know the calendars on gmail

Code:

```js
const timeMin = startOfMonth(new Date(2018, 7, 01));
const timeMax = endOfMonth(new Date(2018, 7, 31));

function getEvents(req, res) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: oauth2Client });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list(
      {
        auth: oauth2Client,
        calendarId: "primary",
        timeMin: timeMin.toISOString(),
        timeMax: timeMax.toISOString(),
        maxResults: 50,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: "startTime"
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(res);
      }
    );
  })
    .then(response => {
      const { items } = response.data;
      //Log out each event> items.forEach(item => console.log(item));
      res.status(200).send(items);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

So how am I supposed to get different gcal events or all in one or what is the solution here? I use oauth2client to authorize the account if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you run that code you are going to have access to the user who authenticates it data.   If you want access to different accounts then each user must authenticate the application.  If you want access at the same time this will probably not be possible using JavaScript.

Normally with server sided programming languages you can have a user authenticate it and save the refresh token then you will have access to their data when they are offline. Then you could technically access multiple users data at the same time.

It is not possible to get a refresh token back in client slide login like JavaScript.

**Update:**

When reqeusting a calendar you need to supply which calendar you would like to see we do that buy specifying the calendar id currrently you are doing

```
calendarId: "primary",
```

Which is the primary calendar of the current authenticated user.  If you have access to other calendars you will need to change this code to be the calendar id of the other user.   You can find the calendar id in google calendar website or you can do a [calendarlist.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) which should show you what calendars that the current user has access to.

Comment: So what is your advice / solution?

* Another question * : is it possible if the guys booking these meeting and such stuff, if they include one specific account so that account get its booked in their schedule too? but without having to be in need of accepting all the invites, if it's possible to change settings or so?

Comment: Advice: Ask them to share their calendars with you then you will be able to access them all.    I don't think i understand the second question.  Why dont you edit your question and give some full example of exactly what your trying to do.

Comment: I am able to log into my google calendar and search for someone's other calendar and I can see it, but it changes color and when I fetch the gcal events I only get mines the blue ones even though someone else's events are in my schedule.. so how do we actually share a calendar properly?

Comment: Check update try and change the calendar id see if you have can see them now. No you cant use more then one at the same time just one at a time.